# Extract the text out of illustrator file, any API or script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working on a project that has 1000 files with the same typo ex. the file with the word "dogs" in text layer that has to be turned into "dog". these 1000 files has the same typo. Is there anyway that I can write a script to do that in Illustrator? or some API that I can extract out text from the file then edit it (change from "dogs" into "dog") then save it back because I don't want to open 1000 files and do it 1000 times.

Comment: Yes, it can be done by scripting (AppleScript, ExtendScript or VBA) See [this](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) for more info

Comment: **I already answered it on [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122860/extract-the-text-out-of-illustrator-file-any-api-or-script) :)**

Comment: Just what I was searching for!